# Convert an unusual integer string to integer value in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have an array of strings containing integer numbers. I need to convert them into integers where possible.

Therefore I do like:

```
if not TryStrToInt ( grid.Cells[columnIndex, i], integerValue ) then begin
  errorsCount := errorsCount + 1;
  errMemo.Lines.Add ( 'Column  "' + fstColumn.Name + '" Line ' + IntTostr ( i ) + ' Value "' + grid.Cells[columnIndex, i] + '" must be integer.' );
end
else begin
   {deal with integerValue}
end;
```

But when `TryStrToInt` faces number like '10.0', '11.00' etc, which actually an Integer, it returns false which proceeds error. `TryStrToInt` in SysUtils.pas implemented as:

```
function TryStrToInt(const S: string; out Value: Integer): Boolean;
var
  E: Integer;
begin
  Val(S, Value, E);
  Result := E = 0;
end;
```

As any other string-number convertions it uses `Val`.

I see only one bad solution like try to convert string to float and then, if successfully, convert float to integer. But it seems ugly.
Is there any other standard way? May be not using Val.

UPD: I use Delphi XE5.

Comment: `10.0` is not an Integer. You might want to use `TryStrToFloat` or parse the string yourself. it not that difficult.

Comment: @kobik , thank you, but it's ugly way I wrote about. I'm looking for graceful solution.

Comment: If you are sure that fractional part always is zero, just extract string part before decimal separator.

Comment: @MBo, certainly I'm not sure. I'm not sure even it's number at all so I had to write this code for check. But '10.0'-like integer values are common in the software from which my data exported. So, I need a correct and universal solution.

Comment: In such case the only approach is to get float value and analyze it's fractional part. Are you expecting some magic function?

Comment: `Val` can work for real numbers too. you could do for e.g. `function MyTryStrToInt(const S: string; out Value: Integer): Boolean;
var
  E: Integer;
  R: Real;
begin
  Val(S, R, E);
  Result := E = 0;
  if Result then Value := Trunc(R);
end;`

Comment: Yep. Also it passes '10.5' too, which is wrong.
Ok, if there is no such magic function like php `intval` perhaps I really have to convert it to float then compare with rounded float then pass or deny. Extremly ugly but works.

Comment: Well, use `Frac` function to check if it's zero. what is "ugly" about this? doesn't php `intval` returns `10` for `10.5`?

Comment: It is about time that you tell us what you consider a **graceful solution**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you require that only numbers with fractional part of zero to be valid Integers you could try this:

```
function MyStrToInt(const S: string; out Value: Integer): Boolean;
var
  E: Integer;
  RealValue: Real;
begin
  Val(S, RealValue, E);
  Result := (E = 0) and (Frac(RealValue) = 0);
  if Result then Value := Trunc(RealValue);
end;
```

Comment: Instead of =0 you should use Math.IsZero because there will be some decimal numbers which cannot be represented in binary for which Frac will be <> 0 by a small margin.

Comment: @dummzeuch, Thanks. I'll leave that to the OP if he wishes.